# Json Object in a single array, need to split values on keys with key meta_value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split, javascript-objects

I have a json object inside a single array, that was an original file that I have deleted some fields, now i want to mutate one of the key values for each entry. Here is some example Json. I Want to loop through and split the meta_value at `http://www.website/wp-content/uploads/` 
right now my code is returning every meta_value as undefined instead of splitting the value, I think it has to do with the loop changing the key value and trying to split it after.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is the code I have so far that generates the json data at the very end

```
var exclusions = [
"ID", "post_author", "post_date_gmt", "post_excerpt", "comment_status", 
"ping_status", "post_password", "to_ping" ,"pinged", "post_modified","post_name",
"post_modified_gmt", "post_content_filtered", "guid", "menu_order", "post_mime_type",
"comment_count", "meta_id", "post_id", "post_type", "post_status"
];
var a = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('final.json'));

a.forEach(obj=>{
  exclusions.forEach(excl=>{
    if(obj[excl] || obj[excl] === ""){
      delete obj[excl];
    }

    if(obj["meta_value"] !== undefined){

      let objTest = obj["meta_value"].split('http://www.fsd.ca/wp-content/uploads/')[1];

      obj["meta_value"] = objTest;


    }

  });
});

console.log(a);
```

Json after initial exclusions

```
[
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-16 23:37:22',
    post_content: `Today we worked at literacy centres. We are writing our own Three Bears story. We are reading with Mrs.Kitson, writing in our life books, working in our printing books and working on making words on the iPads. We use the apps Pocket phonics, magnet board and Montessori crosswords. We went to the library. In the afternoon we went to the gym and watched a play by Quest Theatre. It was called <span style="text-decoration: underline;">For</span> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Art's Sake.</span> They told us that we are all artists and that we should use our imagination. We did zumba. We danced to The chihuahua song. We went to the DPA room and played different tag games. Our hearts worked hard. We had a fun day!`,
    post_title: 'Hometime',
    meta_value: 'http://www.fsd
```

1. List item

.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850631.jpg'
      },
      {
        post_date: '2012-02-21 20:39:19',
        post_content: 'Today we started making our castles. We painted them colourful tissue paper. We are writing our own fairy tales. We read The Princess Frog Fairy Tale. We are making clay dragons and sewing puppets. We went to the gym and skipped. We wrote in our life books an practiced our printing. We had a fun day!',
        post_title: 'Creating Castles',
        meta_value: 'http://www.fd.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850649.jpg'
      },
      {
        post_date: '2012-02-23 21:30:55',
        post_content: 'We talked about the letter E. E is a vowel. There is a vowel in every word. We did our E sheets. We went skating. We had hot chocolate after skating. We worked at new literacy centers. We are doing hard work. We went to Music. We played the bumble bee game. We went to the DPA room to play tag and dance. We went to centers and to the library. We had a fun day!',
        post_title: 'We Have New Pillows',
        meta_value: 'http://www.fds.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850660.jpg'
      },
      {
        post_date: '2012-02-24 19:06:39',
        post_content: 'Today it was Hawaii Day. We wore shorts and summer clothes. We made a Chicka Chicka Boom Boom picture. We made leis. We ate batter dipped pineapples and ate mango, pineapple, papaya, starfruit, dragon fruit and coconut. We tried coconut water. We did the limbo and danced Hawaii style. We sat on our towels and played a math game where we guessed how many candies were under the cup. We wrote in our life books and we went to the big park. We had a fun, fun day!',
        post_title: 'Hawaii Day',
        meta_value: 'http://www.ff.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850665.jpg'
      },
      ... 654 more items
    ]

Json after meta_value key value change, every value is undefined

```
    [
{
    post_date: '2012-02-16 23:37:22',
    post_content: `Today we worked at literacy centres. We are writing our own Three Bears story. We are reading with Mrs.Kitson, writing in our life books, working in our printing books and working on making words on the iPads. We use the apps Pocket phonics, magnet board and Montessori crosswords. We went to the library. In the afternoon we went to the gym and watched a play by Quest Theatre. It was called <span style="text-decoration: underline;">For</span> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Art's Sake.</span> They told us that we are all artists and that we should use our imagination. We did zumba. We danced to The chihuahua song. We went to the DPA room and played different tag games. Our hearts worked hard. We had a fun day!`,
    post_title: 'Hometime',
    meta_value: undefined
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-21 20:39:19',
    post_content: 'Today we started making our castles. We painted them colourful tissue paper. We are writing our own fairy tales. We read The Princess Frog Fairy Tale. We are making clay dragons and sewing puppets. We went to the gym and skipped. We wrote in our life books an practiced our printing. We had a fun day!',
    post_title: 'Creating Castles',
    meta_value: undefined
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-23 21:30:55',
    post_content: 'We talked about the letter E. E is a vowel. There is a vowel in every word. We did our E sheets. We went skating. We had hot chocolate after skating. We worked at new literacy centers. We are doing hard work. We went to Music. We played the bumble bee game. We went to the DPA room to play tag and dance. We went to centers and to the library. We had a fun day!',
    post_title: 'We Have New Pillows',
    meta_value: undefined
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-24 19:06:39',
    post_content: 'Today it was Hawaii Day. We wore shorts and summer clothes. We made a Chicka Chicka Boom Boom picture. We made leis. We ate batter dipped pineapples and ate mango, pineapple, papaya, starfruit, dragon fruit and coconut. We tried coconut water. We did the limbo and danced Hawaii style. We sat on our towels and played a math game where we guessed how many candies were under the cup. We wrote in our life books and we went to the big park. We had a fun, fun day!',
    post_title: 'Hawaii Day',
    meta_value: undefined
  },
  ... 654 more items
]
```

Comment: How did you put a [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) into an array?

Comment: I exported it from wordpress a long time ago, and I no longer have access to that wordpress database.

Comment: I doubt that, please read the linked article, JSON is a textual data exchange format, it doesn't implement any objects.

Comment: well I don't know what I did it was a while ago, it was csv, and then I think i converted to json, I don't know. What exactly is wront with what I have, can I not just change it so it's formatte correctly

Comment: Just read the MDN article ...

Comment: what I will need to do eventually is have this formatted like this https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec so I can import it into sanity.io

Comment: so your saying I don't have json, is your point. I have an array with objects in it

Comment: The code for the meta value shouldn't be inside the `exclusions.forEach` loop. It doesn't do anything related to removing exclusions.

Comment: Yep! People come to see your question expecting to see a question about JSON, they'll get dissapointed badly, since any JSON can't be found ...

Comment: @Teemu Except that most people who come with questions about JSON have the same terminology misunderstanding as he does, so they'll be satisfied.

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be correct. can you try logging `console.log(obj["meta_value"].includes('http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/'))` before `split`

Comment: @AZ_ I get true, false, true, false...

Comment: @Barmar If they just have named JSON as TDEF, nobody would use the term when they're talking about JS objects ...

Comment: @Teemu its would be better just to explain that `JS native object` and `JSON` are not the same thing rather confusing OP that, that's the issue with code.

Comment: @AZ_ Why? Now they really know, because they've read about the subject and studied it by themselves.

Comment: so whenever you get `false` it means your `meta_value` does not include the string you are splitting with and that will end up an array having complete string at 0th position and you will get `undefind` at 1th. so you can keep this `includes` check also with `if(obj["meta_value"] !== undefined){`

Comment: @Barmar had the right solution I had to move the split out of the exlusions for each loop and just inthe a.foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the code to change `obj["meta_value"]` inside the `exclusions.forEach()` loop. So it runs multiple times for the same object. The first time, it replaces `'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850631.jpg'` with `'2012/02/SN850631.jpg'`. The second time, it doesn't find the delimiter `'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/'` in the meta value, so `split()` returns an array with only 1 element, and `[1]` is undefined.

Take it out of the inner loop and it should work correctly.

```js
var exclusions = [
  "ID", "post_author", "post_date_gmt", "post_excerpt", "comment_status",
  "ping_status", "post_password", "to_ping", "pinged", "post_modified", "post_name",
  "post_modified_gmt", "post_content_filtered", "guid", "menu_order", "post_mime_type",
  "comment_count", "meta_id", "post_id", "post_type", "post_status"
];
var a = [
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-16 23:37:22',
    post_content: `Today we worked at literacy centres. We are writing our own Three Bears story. We are reading with Mrs.Kitson, writing in our life books, working in our printing books and working on making words on the iPads. We use the apps Pocket phonics, magnet board and Montessori crosswords. We went to the library. In the afternoon we went to the gym and watched a play by Quest Theatre. It was called <span style="text-decoration: underline;">For</span> <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Art's Sake.</span> They told us that we are all artists and that we should use our imagination. We did zumba. We danced to The chihuahua song. We went to the DPA room and played different tag games. Our hearts worked hard. We had a fun day!`,
    post_title: 'Hometime',
    meta_value: 'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850631.jpg'
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-21 20:39:19',
    post_content: 'Today we started making our castles. We painted them colourful tissue paper. We are writing our own fairy tales. We read The Princess Frog Fairy Tale. We are making clay dragons and sewing puppets. We went to the gym and skipped. We wrote in our life books an practiced our printing. We had a fun day!',
    post_title: 'Creating Castles',
    meta_value: 'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850649.jpg'
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-23 21:30:55',
    post_content: 'We talked about the letter E. E is a vowel. There is a vowel in every word. We did our E sheets. We went skating. We had hot chocolate after skating. We worked at new literacy centers. We are doing hard work. We went to Music. We played the bumble bee game. We went to the DPA room to play tag and dance. We went to centers and to the library. We had a fun day!',
    post_title: 'We Have New Pillows',
    meta_value: 'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850660.jpg'
  },
  {
    post_date: '2012-02-24 19:06:39',
    post_content: 'Today it was Hawaii Day. We wore shorts and summer clothes. We made a Chicka Chicka Boom Boom picture. We made leis. We ate batter dipped pineapples and ate mango, pineapple, papaya, starfruit, dragon fruit and coconut. We tried coconut water. We did the limbo and danced Hawaii style. We sat on our towels and played a math game where we guessed how many candies were under the cup. We wrote in our life books and we went to the big park. We had a fun, fun day!',
    post_title: 'Hawaii Day',
    meta_value: 'http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SN850665.jpg'
  },
];

a.forEach(obj => {
  exclusions.forEach(excl => {
    if (obj[excl] || obj[excl] === "") {
      delete obj[excl];
    }
  });
  if (obj["meta_value"] !== undefined) {
    let objTest = obj["meta_value"].split('http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/')[1];
    obj["meta_value"] = objTest
  }
});

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

At below line 
let objTest = obj["meta_value"].split('http://www.mrskitson.ca/wp-content/uploads/')[1];
When you use split() it returns you empty array and [] of 0th element is not exists.